# How to paste from Windows into Ubuntu 20 shell in the cpanel of my website?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, shell, webserver

I am in the cPanel of my website and the hosting allows me to access the shell (Ubuntu 20). I cannot use simply <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste lines from Windows, Quick Edit Mode isn't active nor can I paste with right click. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Hi Andrea, have you tried middle click? My Ubuntu PC has this bound to "Paste", and I use it a lot to paste commands on the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work.